.NET 8 Rate Limiting via Policy
I am trying to run the .NET 8 Rate Limiting Middleware, with a global rate limit, as well as a specific policy for certain endpoints. The global policy is working as expected, but I cannot get the endpoint specific policy to work.
I have added the following into my Startup.cs
private void AddRateLimiter(IServiceCollection services)
{
    logger.Information("Adding Rate Limiter");
    services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
    {
        options.OnRejected = async (context, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 429;

            if (context.Lease.TryGetMetadata(MetadataName.RetryAfter, out var retryAfter))
            {
                await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
                    $"Too many requests. Please try again after {retryAfter.TotalMinutes} minute(s). ", cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
                    "Too many requests. Please try again later. ", cancellationToken);
            }
        };

        options.AddPolicy("ThrottlePolicy", request =>
        {
            var ipAddress = request.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"X-Forwarded-For: {ipAddress}");

            return RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(ipAddress, partition =>
                new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
                {
                    AutoReplenishment = true,
                    PermitLimit = 2,
                    Window = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
                });
        });


        options.GlobalLimiter = PartitionedRateLimiter.CreateChained(
        PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpContext, string>(request =>
        {
            var ipAddress = request.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"X-Forwarded-For (1-minute window): {ipAddress}");

            return RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(ipAddress, partition =>
                new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
                {
                    AutoReplenishment = true,
                    PermitLimit = 300,
                    Window = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
                });
        }),
        PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpContext, string>(request =>
        {
            var ipAddress = request.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"X-Forwarded-For (1-hour window): {ipAddress}");

            return RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(ipAddress, partition =>
                new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
                {
                    AutoReplenishment = true,
                    PermitLimit = 3000,
                    Window = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
                });
        }));
    });
}

And then on the controller endpoint I have:
 [EnableRateLimiting(policyName: "ThrottlePolicy")]
 [Authorize(Policy = "ViewPolicy")]
 [HttpPost("{incident_Id}/[controller]")]
 [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
 [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(FileModel))]
 public Task<IActionResult> Post(string incident_Id, [FromForm] FilePostModel evidence)
 {
     return HandleRequestAsync(new FileAddRequest()
     {
         IncidentId = incident_Id,
         NewEntity = evidence
     });
 }

With the Console Logging I can see the global policies being hit, but I never get any logging for the ThrottlePolicy. Not sure what I'm missing here.
EDIT: I have figured this out, I had to add the following:
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});


I would suggest to start your debugging with the following: app.MapGet("/testThrottling", () => Results.Ok("Testing")).RequireRateLimiting("ThrottlePolicy"); So, create a endpoint with Minimal API and check whether it works or not. That can narrow down whether your problem is at the Controller side or on the rate limiter definitions side.

Hi @PeterCsala - If I do that, then it works as expected. So must be something Controller end.

Cool, then try to add the attributes one by one to the controller method and see when it starts misbehaving.

I have removed everything except the [HttpPost("{incident_Id}/[controller]")] and it still doesnt work. I am wondering if its the way its being set up, as I'm Using IApplicationBuilder in the Configure Method. The global policy works but the endpoint specific doesnt, so I dont know if its something nuanced around not doing MapControllers or something

I can see that you have found the solution. Congratulation. Please do not edit your question with the solution rather leave a post and mark it as the answer.

I have figured this out, I had to add the following:
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});


Could you please elaborate why these were the missing pieces?

Your posted code works for me but I am unable to see how you are calling UseRateLimiter(). You do have to configure the rate limiter as you did in AddRateLimiter method AND then call app.UseRateLimiter() as shown in a sample program.cs code. Without this piece you have configured your rate limiter options, but not told the application to actually use them.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

//Your existing logic here... 
AddRateLimiter(builder.Services);

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

//Not able to see that you called this. 
app.UseRateLimiter();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


Hi, I am calling app.UseRateLimiter() in the Configure Method:  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env) { var logger = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILogger<Startup>>(); ServiceLogger.LogEnvironment(logger); ServiceLogger.LogConfiguration(logger, Configuration); AddUseExceptionHandler(app); MigrateDataToSqlServer(app); app.UseRateLimiter();
